# Credential Management API Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, credentials

How to implement Credential Management API in Flutter?

I want save login Credential in Google. How to invoke Credential Management API in browser?

Comment: Seems like there is a [password_credential](https://pub.dev/packages/password_credential) package written for that, you can take a look if it satisfies your needs. It is also an open source, so you can take a look at the code if you don't want to use package.

Comment: You can use the JWT token and manage it with the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package, it's so easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autofillgroup to save your Credential in browser and sync with your google account.

```
return Form(
      
        key: _mobileKey,
        child: AutofillGroup(
            child: FocusScope(
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: mobileController,
                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.telephoneNumber],

                autofocus: true,
                maxLength: 10,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                ],
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                // move to the next field
                // onEditingComplete: _node.nextFocus,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Enter Your Mobile Number",
                ),
                // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your mobile number';
                  } else if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Enter Valid mobile number';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
]))));
```

you can use it for specified builtin keyword.
example

```
autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.name]
```

remember you cant use your own keyword